# Ubuntu 14.04 gnutls_handshake failed

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, apt, gnutls

While trying to install mkl library in Ubuntu 14.04 docker image, I am getting a gnutls_handshake failed error

To reproduce

```
docker pull mxnetci/publish.ubuntu1404_cpu
docker run -it mxnetci/publish.ubuntu1404_cpu sh
```

Install intel mkl

```
wget -qO - wget https://apt.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS-2019.PUB | apt-key add -
sh -c "echo deb https://apt.repos.intel.com/mkl all main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-mkl.list"
apt-get update
```

Error

```
Err http://apt.repos.intel.com all/main amd64 Packages
  gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
```

Refer steps : https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-intel-free-libs-and-python-apt-repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last version of MKL that supports Ubuntu 14.04 is MKL2018

- https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-2018-system-requirements.html

Post that, MKL doesn't support Ubuntu 14.04 anymore.

- https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-2020-system-requirements.html
- https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-2019-system-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is related to installation. MKL's system requirements contain only those OS's which are validated by this version of mkl. It means that if you copy mkl's binaries to requested OS, we expect MKL will work on Ubuntu v14. The same questions were regarding RH5 support, as an example.

Comment: how will you copy binaries if official website prevents you to fetch it